# React error - unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Que tal estoy tratando de resolver un error que me da al actualizar el **state**
despues de una peticion ajax

alguna idea de como resolver este error? estoy utilizando **Sweetalert** para mostrar los mensajes al hacer las peticiones.

**unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering.**

```
 constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state ={
           showmodal: false,
           modal: {
              title: '',
              icon: "success",
              type: "success",
              text: ""
            },
         }
}

handleSubmitevent(){
    axios.post('url/to/myApi').then((success) => {
            let dataOptions = this.state.modal;
            dataOptions.text = "exito";
            dataOptions.icon = "success";
            dataOptions.type = "success";
        this.setState({ showmodal: false, modal: dataOptions });
    });
}
```

```
render(){
let mensaje = <SweetAlert show={ this.state.showmodal } 
                                    confirmButtonText="Continuar" 
                                    confirmButtonColor="#3085d6" 
                                    type={this.state.modal.type} 
                                    title = {this.state.modal.title } 
                                    text = {this.state.modal.text}  
                                    onConfirm = { () => { this.setState({ showmodal: true}); }
                                } />

return (
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitevent}>
       <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.producto} name="producto" onChange={event => this.setState({producto:event.target.value}) }></input>
       <input type="number" min="0" className="form-control" name="precio" value={(this.state.precio != null) ? this.state.precio : ''   } onChange={event => this.setState({precio:event.target.value})}></input>
       <button type="submit"  className="btn btn-primary col-md-3"></button>
    </form>
{mensaje}
    )
}
```

[image: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering.]

Comment: Por favor muéstranos algo más de código, ¿dónde llamas a la función `handleSubmitevent`?

Comment: tengo un formulario que ejecuta la funcion  <form onSubmit={this. handleSubmitevent}>, valido los campos y al final ejecuto el ajax

Comment: `onConfirm = { () => { this.setState({ showmodal: true}); }` El modal abierto vuelve a lanzar la orden de abrir de nuevo?

Comment: hice un copy paste para ejemplificar,  es false para ocultar el modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haré una respuesta un poco corta, sin entrar a mucho detalle de qué sucede, pero básicamente estás modificando el objeto state directamente, lo cual puede ocasionar muchos tipos de errores, entre esos el que te ocurre.

Debes tener en cuenta que al correr esto: `let dataOptions = this.state.modal` no estás creando una copia del objeto, si no que estás creando una variable llamada `dataOptions` la cual apunta a la misma dirección de memoria de `this.state.modal` por lo que cualquier modificación que haces en `dataOptions` en realidad la estás haciendo sobre `this.state.modal`, es decir, estás haciendo algo como esto `this.state.modal.text = "exito"` cuando eso deberías hacerlo es en un `setState` como dice la documentación de React

Por eso es mejor asignar creando una copia del objeto en sí, podrías cambiar tu método para que quede de esta forma:

```
handleSubmitevent() {
  axios.post('url/to/myApi').then((success) => {
    let dataOptions = {
      ...this.state.modal,
      text: "exito",
      icon: "success",
      type: "success",
    }
    this.setState({ showmodal: true, modal: dataOptions });
  });
}
```

Comment: gracias @german-alzate por la respuesta tkm